# Angular 2 QuickStart <script /> failing

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I manually created the [5 Min Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) of Angular 2 following the web instructions.
The application was near identically to the QuickStart tutorial. But I imported the .js files like this:

```
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js" />
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js" />
<script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js" />
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js" />
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js" />
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js" />
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js" />
```

Changing them like the following, makes the application work:

```
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js></script>   
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
```

Can anybody explain this weird (at least for me) behaviour?

Comment: `script` tag is not self closing in nature..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In HTML the script element has a mandatory start tag and a mandatory end tag. You cannot omit the end tag. This is simply how HTML is designed.

If you want some historical background:

In the beginning HTML elements generally:

- Contained content and had mandatory start and end tags
- Contained content, but only allowed a limited selection of child elements, so the end tag was optional as it could be inferred by the presence of an element that was not allowed as a child. (e.g. `<p>`)
- As above, but could be used in only very limited places so the *start* tag was also optional (e.g. `<body>`)
- Could not contain content (e.g. `<img>`) so the end tag for forbidden

`<script>` was introduced at this time. It can contain content (inline scripts) so the start and end tags were required.

Then along came XHTML. In XHTML `<foo />` and `<foo></foo>` meant exactly the same thing. Except you needed an XML parser, and browsers didn't use them to parse HTML (since HTML is not XML so it would error). You could serve the document as `application/xhtml+xml` which would trigger the XML parser … except it would then break if the browser didn't have one … and you'd get a yellow screen of death if you did have one but the author made a tiny well-formedness error.

So almost everyone gave up on XHTML.

Then came HTML 5 which was designed to be backwards compatible and forwards compatible.

In HTML 5 `<foo />` means the same as `<foo>` so that the terminally XML addicted can continue to put a `/` at the end of the image start tags.

In HTML 5 there are a host of new elements, but old browsers don't know about them, so when they were introduced the start and end tags for all of them were made mandatory so that browsers that didn't recognise them (and so couldn't infer where the end tag was supposed to go) wouldn't choke up on the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

Script tags can't be self closed, as specified by the various W3C standards.

[C.3. Element Minimization and Empty Element Content](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_3)

> Given an empty instance of an element whose content model is not EMPTY (for example, an empty title or paragraph) do not use the minimized form (e.g. use `<p> </p>` and not `<p />`).

[A.1.1. XHTML-1.0-Strict](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#a_dtd_XHTML-1.0-Strict)

```
    <!ENTITY % Script "CDATA">
        <!-- script expression -->
```